# javascript string length returning undefined

Tags: javascript, string, casting, undefined

I cant seem to get a string length from a value in a form textfield
Here's the code for my function, its getting passed the parameter of the textfields name

```
  function validate(thing)
  {

  var location = document.getElementById(thing);

  var cardst = location.value;
  window.alert (cardst);
  cardst = String(cardst);
  window.alert (cardst.lenght);
```

the first alert works, it alerts whatever I type into the textfield, but the second one is always undefined. As you can see I did cast it as a string but I get get undefined.. ANy ideas??

Comment: Typo: `cardst.lenght` should be `cardst.length`; Also, not sure of the reason for creating a new string.

Comment: Using "location" as variable name is a bad idea. How do you call your function?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That would be because you misspelled `length` :-)

Use this instead:

```
cardst.length;   // <- 'th', not 'ht'
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a syntax error. It's length not lenght

```
   function validate(thing)
  {

  var location = document.getElementById(thing);

  var cardst = location.value;
  window.alert (cardst);
  cardst = String(cardst);
  window.alert (cardst.lenght);
                           ^ /*should read window.alert(cardst.length)*/
```

Comment: try ctrl+shift+j on most browsers